# "object index is not a member of package views.html" when opening scala play project in scala ide

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0

I've created a play project with play 2.3.7

In the project directory, I ran activator and ran the `eclipse` command to generate eclipse project files.

When I go to eclipse (I'm using the Scala IDE from typesafe Build id: 4.0.0-vfinal-20150119-1023-Typesafe , there is an error in my Application.scala file:

```
object index is not a member of package views.html
```

Is there something amiss with my setup? The app runs fine when I execute `run` at the activation console prompt.

Thanks!

EDIT: Added code

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

}
```

The error is on the 'Ok..' line.

There is a file in views called index.scala.html, and the app runs file when I run it from activator..

Comment: Can you show us the code where the compiler complains?

Comment: I suspect that the play2 plugin is not compatible with scala ide 4. I will try to switch to scala ide 3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104968/scala-ide-4-0-0-thinks-theres-errors-in-an-out-of-the-box-play-framework-2-3-7

Comment: Please post your `build.sbt`

Answer (score 29):

Occasionally after adding a view in Play 2.4.x, IntelliJ IDEA sometimes gets confused and absolutely refuses to build. Even rebuild Project fails:

[image]

This still happens from time-to-time in IDEA 15. And when it does, the command line provides the quickest, most-reliable fix:

> sbt clean; sbt compile

That's it! IDEA will now compile the project as expected.

Update:

In the rare case that `sbt compile` completed successfully on the command line, but IntelliJ IDEA 15 still gives the same "object x is not a member" error, then this has solved IDEA's confusion:

File Menu:

[image]

Comment: It worked for me but not until I opened the Terminal in Intellij 15 and then installed sbt with Homebrew i.e brew install sbt.  There after, the sbt clean; sbt combile was enough to make remove the bug. Thanks!

Comment: This solution also fixed my issue. By chance, did you change the version of Scala used via IJ in the middle of rebuilds? I did this and it seems to have triggered it, requiring me to use `sbt clean; sbt compile` from the terminal.

Comment: @ThomasFarvour Not that I recall, but good idea to keep in mind. I haven't seen it happen lately (since I've been using IDEA 16.1 EAP).

Comment: @BrentFoust turns out in my case, I had to manually add back `target/scala-2.11/routes/main` to the list of sources in my root module defined in sbt. I suspect this is an IntelliJ bug during the auto-import phase of sbt as others seem to have indicating having to do this for twirl.

Comment: Was having OP's exact problem, and this solution, specifically the Invalidate Caches, worked for me. Running IntelliJ with play 2.6.0. I had to manually update the Scala, SBT and Play versions in my build and properties files to be the most up to date and then used this solution.

Answer (score 12):

The other solutions did not work for me. Some would give me different errors, some would clear the Problems tab but leave me with a red squiggle under `views.html.index` and auto-complete would not work with the scala.html templates.

What finally worked was to open the project's properties, go to `Java Build Path > Source`, and add both of the following directories:

```
target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main
target/scala-2.11/twirl/main
```

If you only do `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main` then you'll miss out on the class files generated from the `conf` directory.

Comment: Note: when you do `sbt eclipse`, the custom project properties above get overwritten. I'm still looking for a solution that gets these directories into the Eclipse classpath w/o getting lost on that operation, I suspect it involves editing `build.sbt`, but I'm not quite sure how yet. I'll edit my answer when I find it.

Comment: Update: I just use IntelliJ w/ Scala and SBT plugin now

Comment: Had same issues with IntelliJ 2016.1. This solution works fine for me.

Comment: @einnocent .... I can't find **target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main** directory. I have only **target/scala-2.11/twirl/main**

Comment: Many will hit this page again and again.

Answer (score 8):

In [Scala IDE 4.0.0 thinks there's errors in an out-of-the-box Play Framework 2.3.7 program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104968/scala-ide-4-0-0-thinks-theres-errors-in-an-out-of-the-box-play-framework-2-3-7) you can find the solution (in brief: adding `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main` folder to the compilation path), give it a try.

Comment: Adding that folder to the Java Build Path > Source removes the original error from the Problems tab, but adds three more, all: `not found: value routes`

Comment: I have never found such error. But in [this other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196123/scala-play-not-found-value-routes-eclipse-and-idea) they discuss that same problem. Could it be that your routes file is empty?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I added `target/scala-2.x/classes` and `target/scala-2.x/classes_managed` to my Java build path and Eclipse stopped complaining.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue running Play 2.4.0-RC1 using default SBT layout (`disablePlugins(PlayLayoutPlugin)`) and solved it by adding to `build.sbt`:

```
sourceDirectories in (Compile, TwirlKeys.compileTemplates) :=
    (unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile).value
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main` which is having `views.html` package to source fixed for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.  Not sure why the plugin doesn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

@brent-foust 's answer worked for me but only initially.  Every time I rebuilt the project from within IDEA I would then get "not found: routes" errors from within `target\scala-2.11\twirl\main\views\html\main.template.scala` until I performed Brent's workaround again.

I eventually discovered the solution to that was changing a line in the .iml file from

```
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main" />
```

to

```
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main" isTestSource="false" />
```

I don't know what the long term implications of doing this are but it has fixed this problem.  Some of the other similar problems mentioned might also be fixed by applying the same change to some of the other folders listed in the .iml.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all solutions without any positiv result.
So I went to `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > sbt` and checked `Use sbt shell` for imports and builds.
This let the compile button in intelliJ compile with the sbt shell.
I think this is better anyway, since a build server or something similar will compile the same way and not like intelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

For me when importing the project into intellij making sure I "checked" the "auto import" checkbox did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the following line to your sbt.build file:

```
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)
```

2) Add the follwing line to your plugins.sbt file under the project folder:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.1.0")
```

3) Run the "eclipse" command from within sbt

as explained in the documentation of the play framework:

[Setting up your preferred IDE](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE)

Answer (score 0):

Basically we need a way to put the compiled classes on the path for this to work.

I did the following to fix it.
Since the projects compiles to the `target` directory.
I went to the `Project Properties` -> Java Build Path and added a few folders that look like this,

target/scala-2.12/routes/main
target/scala-2.12/twirl
target/scala-2.12/twirl/main

Now i dont want you to assume you will have these exact folders in your case too. That depends on your project setup.
But you should add the folders inside the target/scala-2.x folder.