# activator eclipse command shows sbt.ResolveException

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator, sbteclipse

I have created a new project by using `activator new simple play-scala` command.`simple` is my project name.I would like to import this project into my eclipse(ScalaIDE),so I used `activator eclipse` command but It showed the below Exception

```
[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)
 [error] Not a valid project ID: eclipse 
[error] Expected ':' [error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean) 
[error] eclipse [error]
```

for this error I added `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")` https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE command in `simple/project/plugins.sbt` It resolved the above mentioned error but It shows the error

```
 [warn]            +- default:simple_test-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10,
    sbtVersion=0.13)
    sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-
    plugin;4.0.0: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRet
ries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:
97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1369)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1365)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1
399)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1
397)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:22
6)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:22
6)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestric
tions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt
eclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;4.0.0: not found
```

**sbt version: =0.13.8**
**scalaVersion: =2.11.6**

I tried with `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "3.0.0")` this too It built the eclipse project succeesfully but It showed the error

**Applications.scala**

```
object index is not a member of package views.html
```

**index.scala.html,main.scala.html**

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- type Html is not a member of package play.api.templates
- type Html is not a member of package play.api.templates
- type Html is not a member of package play.api.templates
- object HtmlFormat is not a member of package
play.api.templates
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, ScalaIDE is still under development and not yet as stable as Eclipse JDT. As far as I know, especially the Play support still has some problems. However, with activator/sbt you can compile, test, and run your Play code without any problems.

But lets look at your error messages. I assume that you want to get rid of them. ;)

1. use `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "3.0.0")`. 4.0.0 is not final/available yet.
2. `object index is not a member of package views.html`.
   Look at the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458597/object-index-is-not-a-member-of-package-views-html-when-opening-scala-play-pro). There exists no general solution yet. However, for me it worked to include two more source folders in the project's build path:

   ```
   target/scala-2.11/routes/main
   target/scala-2.11/twirl/main
   ```
3. `type Html is not a member of package play.api.templates` etc. I have no idea how this can be fixed. But if you close the html file after making your changed and then do a clean build all error messages will be gone.

**Update:** there is a discussion in the [Scala IDE User group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-ide-user/WFNoQ6GNw1k) regarding issue 3. However, no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. 
Setting the sbteclipse plugin version to an earlier version does not work, as sbt steadfastly refuses it, and discards it for version 4.0, which is not available.
Sbt is a pain...even their website has no documentation about this issue, which by the looks of it, is at least one year old?