# Scala Play: object index is not a member of package views.html

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm getting

```
object index is not a member of package views.html
```

but unlike all the other threads opened on this subject, my issue seems totally unrelated to the IDE. I get this issue from the command line (no IDE) no matter how much I try to clean and rebuild by running

```
activator clean compile run
```

or just

```
sbt clean compile
```

Here is my conf/routes:

```
GET      /                   controllers.Application.index
GET      /books              controllers.Application.listBooks
POST     /books              controllers.Application.upload

GET     /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

This si my views/index.scala.html:

```
@import play.api.data.Form
@import models.Book

@(form: Form[Book])(implicit messages: Messages)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>xxx</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")'>
        <script type="text/javascript" href='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")'></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="screenshot">

            <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a> <a class="brand" href="#">Workday Dublin CTF</a>

                        <div class="nav-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <h1>All Your Books Are Belong To Us</h1>
                <div class="container">

                    <h2>Add Book</h2>
                    @helper.form(action = routes.Application.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {

                        @helper.inputText(form("title"))
                        @helper.inputText(form("author"))
                        @helper.inputFile(form("myUpload"))

                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Book</button>
                        </div>
                    }

                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, here is where the error is thrown, in my controllers/Application.scala:

```
package controllers

import models.Book
import models.Book._
import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(Book.form))
  }

  def listBooks = Action {
    Ok(books.head.myUpload)
  }

  def upload() = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body.file("myUpload").map { myUpload =>
      import java.io.File
      val filename = myUpload.filename
      val contentType = myUpload.contentType
      myUpload.ref.moveTo(new File(s"/tmp/$filename"))
      addBook(Book("xxxtitle", "xxxauthor", filename))
      Ok("File uploaded at /tmp/"+filename)
    }.getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
        "error" -> "Missing file")
    }
  }
}
```

The error is thrown at Ok(views.html.index(Book.form)) which references models/Book.scala:

```
package models

import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._

case class Book(title: String, author: String, myUpload: String)

object Book {

  var books = List(Book("title test 1", "author test 1", "filename test 1"))

  def addBook(book: Book) = books = books ::: List(book)

  val form = Form(mapping(
    "title" -> text,
    "author" -> text,
    "myUpload" -> nonEmptyText)(Book.apply)(Book.unapply))
}
```

As I've researched a lot about this, and no other solution has worked so far, any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: this import `import views.html.index`  is not required

Comment: Hi @pamu thanks. That was leftover from one of my attempts to solve the issue. I've removed it now but I still get the same error. (gonna update the original post, too)

Comment: from where `(implicit messages: Messages)` is coming? There is no implicit defined by you anywhere or is it related to Internationalization ?

Comment: try using `implicit req` inside action `def index = Action { implicit req =>
    Ok(views.html.index(Book.form))
  }`

Comment: @curious I had to add that in order to avoid the following error "index.scala.html:39: could not find implicit value for parameter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages [error] @helper.inputText(form("author"))"

Comment: @pamu thanks a million but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error even after applying your suggestion (and doing activator clean compile run)

Comment: can you try moving the import statements below the `@(form)` args declaration in the template?

Comment: thanks @tksfz but no, that didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, even in this case the issue was related to the IDE. Despite seemingly unrelated, given it occurred from the command line and even after applying all the changes [suggested by others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458597/object-index-is-not-a-member-of-package-views-html-when-opening-scala-play-pro).

I created a new project -> Play 2.x in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.2. Then I copy/paste all the content from the old faulty project, within in the new project structure. And everything worked straight away, although I had to add

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
```

to Application.scala in order to pass the implicit messages (as @curious spotted in the comments). I did not mark his comment as the answer because when I tried to add these imports in the faulty project, I was still getting the same error. So nope, the fix would be something to do wth the IDE settings which I still am not too sure about. Surely my workaround is good enough for me, though.

Answer (score 2):

Delete all content from folder **/project/target** and build on terminal:
**sbt compile**