# How to build a play project in Intellij IDEA 2016.2.2?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have created a new play project in Intellij IDEA 2016.2.2 according to the tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html (the section "Creating a project"). As a result I have got a project with file `Application.scala` containing:

```
package controllers
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
class Application extends Controller {
    def index = Action {
        Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
    }
}
```

Then I tried to build it using `Build` -> `Rebuild project` command. But I get build error:

```
Error:(9, 19) object index is not a member of package views.html
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
```

After starting the app using `Run` -> `Run 'Play2Run'` and including the `target`  folder to the build process I managed to build the project via `Build` -> `Rebuild project`. But what should I do before building in the case I haven't launched the app via `play`?

**Explanation why my question is not duplicate of another question**: 
I haven't found `clean project` opportunity in IntelliJ. Invalidating cache of IntelliJ doesn't help as well. Also the directories `target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main` and `target/scala-2.11/twirl/main` are absent in this new project. They emerge after `Run 'Play2Run'` and after that I can configure this Java Build Path, but I want to avoid using `Run 'Play2Run'`. How can I create these directories without the `Run 'Play2Run'`?

Comment: Create a new Run Configuration – From the main menu, select Run -> Edit Configurations
Click on the + to add a new configuration
From the list of configurations, choose “SBT Task”
In the “tasks” input box, simply put “run”
Apply changes and select OK.
Now you can choose “Run” from the main Run menu and run your application docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/IDE#intellij

Comment: @ALEX_AME In this case I get the same build error.

Comment: Alright, well I know this does not solve your issue but if you just want to start the application, download activator, navigate to the directory and type "activator run".

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["object index is not a member of package views.html" when opening scala play project in scala ide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458597/object-index-is-not-a-member-of-package-views-html-when-opening-scala-play-pro)

Comment: Official jetbrains documentation for this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html

Comment: @MarioPetrovic I have mentioned this documentation at the beginning of my question...